# Translate my app name

Tags: facebook, translation

I'm doing an app to a global company that have a different name per language. They would like to have only one app (it's better one app with 1 million users that 20 with 50k).

It's possible to have a different app name per locale? In the Translations Admin Panel this seems possible, as it's possible to translate the app name. In practice the name is always the original...

Many thanks for your help!